# how to call a wrapper's method in react

Tags: reactjs, components, mixins

I'm using a hoc to wrap a component. This hoc dispatches an action when unmounted. To do so, it calls a 'resetState' method. But what if I want to call that same `resetState()` at another place in the wrapped component. `this.resetState` does not work (logically), I only can imagine passing the function as a prop to the wrapper.

```
const resetAtUnmount = function (type) {
  // return the function to be called by redux 'connect'
  return function decorate(WrappedComponent) {
    // return the final class
    return class extends React.Component {
      resetState() {
        store.dispatch({ type });
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        this.resetState();
      }

      render() {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      }
    };
  };
};
```

export default resetAtUnmount;

Comment: Use action to dispatch resetState

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you answered your own question. Pass resetState as a prop: `<WrappedComponent {...this.props} resetState={this.resetState} />`

Comment: How will call the resetState method from the wrapped component(Child component)